# Arrayformula + SUM + INDIRECT

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to get the spreadsheet to use the value of L2 as a reference to calculate the cash value at the moment:

[image]

From the formula:

```
=arrayformula(IF(I2:I<>"",$L$2+SUM(INDIRECT("G2:G"&I2:I)),""))
```

But the lines below always return the same result, in this case 100.

I wonder where I am going wrong in creating this formula

**Another detail:**

I have made a chart ready to treat this cash growth over time, if you decide to help by looking straight at the spreadsheet, by re-adjusting the correct formula, please also take a look if the chart is working correctly according to the data and the movement of values, always the last row of columns G and H at the beginning of the graph

**This is the expected result in Bank Column:**
Capture the initial bankroll `L2` and from it add the sequence of results achieved in each investment in `COLUMN G`

[image]

[Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GjxhATcZvacNBKL3mxwI2zuqqnc87lP1BHK0e9NfTTI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: what should be the output? can you include example?

Comment: @player0 I added the expected result in my question. I'm sorry for missing this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(L2+MMULT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(REPT("0×", 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(D2:D)+1))-1)&
 TEXTJOIN("×", 1, INDEX(SORT({INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(D2:D)+1), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(D2:D)+1))}, 2, 0),,1)), "×"), 999^99, 
 COUNTA(D2:D)+1)*1, ROW(INDIRECT("G1:G"&COUNTA(D2:D)+1))^0), 
 "offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]